# Cucumber reports values inside code

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, selenide

Is there some way to get these cucumber report values inside code in some variables?

For example:

```
int scenariosRun = cucumber.getScenarios(); // 8
int scenariosPassed = cucumber.getScenariosPassed(); // 8
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get current scenario details in the after/before hook as given below,

```
@Before
public void before(Scenario scenario) {
    System.out.println("------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Starting - " + scenario.getName());
    System.out.println("------------------------------");
}

@After
public void before(Scenario scenario) {
    System.out.println("------------------------------");
    System.out.println(scenario.getName() + " Status - " + scenario.getStatus());
    System.out.println("------------------------------");
}
```

Comment: hm... where should I place these methods? I have some AbstractRunner, but I use BeforeClass and AfterClass there. Not Before and After.

Comment: any where in your step definition class.